# Use predicted data to improve Multinomial Naive Bayes model for text classification

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, naive-bayes-classifier

For a small project, I am making use of Naïve Bayes Multinomial Model to do some text classification. It has shown some very promising results, especially since I don't have a lot of Training data.

Currently, it happens that some predictions are false, but would it be possible to reuse the text and the corrected class to "improve" the model ?

E.g.: My model has to classify text as either sports, or politics. Let's image that the model classifies text *t = "Ronaldo plays at Juventus."* as being politics, which is not the case. Would it be possible to "reinject" text *t* with the correct class into the model, in order to improve it ?

Is it good practice within Machine Learning ?

My model is a basic Multinomial Naïve Bayes (using Sklearn) and makes use of TFIDF and SpaCy to remove unnecessary words from the text (like stop-words, etc.).